# UI shows past search results for split second before showing new results React

Tags: reactjs

this is the most annoying UI behavior ever. I have a search which renders names that match the query or shows a "no results found"

```
  const handleSearch = async (value: string) => {
    if (value === "") {
      setSearch("");
      fetcher.data = undefined;
    } else {
      fetcher.load(`/query?q=${value}`);
      setSearch(value);
    }
  };
```

```
{search.length > 0 && <Search result={fetcher.data} />}
```

```
const Search: React.FC<SearchProps> = ({ result }) => {
  return (
    <ul>
      {result &&
        (result.length > 0 ? (
          result.map(({ name, id }) => (
            <Link to={`/characters/${id}`} key={id}>
              <li>{name}</li>
            </Link>
          ))
        ) : (
          <p>No matches found :(</p>
        ))}
    </ul>
  );
};const Search: React.FC<SearchProps> = ({ result }) => {
  return (
    <ul>
      {result &&
        (result.length > 0 ? (
          result.map(({ name, id }) => (
            <Link to={`/characters/${id}`} key={id}>
              <li>{name}</li>
            </Link>
          ))
        ) : (
          <p>No matches found :(</p>
        ))}
    </ul>
  );
};
```

If I am to enter something, clear the value of the input, and then enter a new value, for a second I see the old search results and it causes an incredibly annoying and not pleasant height glitch in the UI as the content changes for the search results.

I know this is somewhat ambiguous but if anyone has had similar problems in react and knows of any solutions I would love to hear them.

Comment: Isn't your code duplicated ?

Comment: Please provide a MCVE (ex: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/)

Comment: I guess you have to put  `setSearch(value);` before  `fetcher.load('/query?q=${value}');`  in `handleSearch ` function